# install python bindings via pip

Tags: mongodb, pip, ansible, pymongo

I am trying to install python bindings through ansible:

```
- name: install mongodb python bindings via pip
  pip: name=pymongo version="{{mongodb_version}}"
```

version: 3.2

Error message:

```
    "stderr": "  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f66cdb224d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/pymongo/\n  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f66cdb22c90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/pymongo/\n  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f66cdb22e10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/pymongo/\n  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f66cdb22f90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/pymongo/\n  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f66cdacc150>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/pymongo/\n  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pymongo==3.2 (from versions: )\nNo matching distribution found for pymongo==3.2\nYou are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 19.2.3 is available.\nYou should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.", 
    "stderr_lines": [
        "  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f66cdb224d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/pymongo/", 
        "  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f66cdb22c90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/pymongo/", 
        "  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f66cdb22e10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/pymongo/", 
        "  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f66cdb22f90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/pymongo/", 
        "  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f66cdacc150>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/pymongo/", 
        "  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pymongo==3.2 (from versions: )", 
        "No matching distribution found for pymongo==3.2",
```

I have exported proxy variables before this step.

I have added the proxy code here, please have a look.

```
- name: Set http proxy variables in /etc/profile
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/profile
    line: 'export http_proxy={{http_proxy}}'
  when: http_proxy is defined

- name: Set https proxy variables in /etc/profile
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/profile
    line: 'export https_proxy={{https_proxy}}'
  when: https_proxy is defined

- name: Set http proxy variables in /etc/profile
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/profile
    line: 'export HTTP_PROXY={{http_proxy}}'
  when: http_proxy is defined

- name: Set https proxy variables in /etc/profile
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/profile
    line: 'export HTTPS_PROXY={{https_proxy}}'
  when: https_proxy is defined

- name: Source the bashrc file
  action: shell source /etc/profile
```

If I run shell command manually on servers, `/usr/bin/pip install pymongo===3.2`, it works fine but when I do it through ansible, it fails

Comment: `I have exported proxy variables before this step.` <-- depending on how you have done this it is likely not persistent. Can you share this step as well please?

Comment: @MattP, I have added the proxy code here , these are the tasks just before python bindings install step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are trying to set environment variables is not persistent between Ansible tasks. You should use the `environment` directive, either at a task or a play level.

For example (task level):

```
- name: install mongodb python bindings via pip
  pip: name=pymongo version="{{mongodb_version}}"
  environment:
    http_proxy: "{{ http_proxy }}"
    https_proxy: "{{ https_proxy }}"
```

Or (play level):

```
- hosts: all
  environment:
    http_proxy: "{{ http_proxy }}"
    https_proxy: "{{ https_proxy }}"
```